# Stored Procedure com parâmetro de saída sendo o Id da última inserção. C#

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, sql-server, ado.net

Olá, estou realizando uma inserção em uma tabela, porém preciso que ela retorne o ID que acabou de inserir. Pesquisei sobre o comando `OUTPUT` porém não consegui resolver o meu problema. Preciso fazer tudo isto usando procedures, ou seja, também preciso saber como "pegar" este retorno da procedure.

Procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SaveProfessionalUser
@id int,
@title varchar(50)

AS
BEGIN       
    INSERT INTO ProfessionalType VALUES (@title)
END
```

Codebehind:

```
using (_context)
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SaveProfessionalUser");
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idProfessionalUser", pUser.IdProfessionalUser);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@title", pUser.Title);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    this._context.ExecuteProcedure(cmd);

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Se ta fazendo com Entity Framework ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Abra outro comando e use o seguinte:

```
SELECT IDENT_CURRENT ('ProfessionalUser') AS UltimoIdInserido;
```

Há outras alternativas, como [`@@IDENTITY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187342.aspx) e [`SCOPE_IDENTITY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx), mas elas são relativas a todas as tabelas ou à sessão toda, o que não é muito seguro.

Se fosse uma `query` normal, há também a [declaração `OUTPUT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx), mas como você está executando uma `PROCEDURE`, o `IDENT_CURRENT` é o ideal.

Esse jeito que você está usando tá um pouco esquisito, mas fica assim:

```
using (_context)
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SaveProfessionalUser");
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idProfessionalUser", pUser.IdProfessionalUser);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@title", pUser.Title);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    this._context.ExecuteProcedure(cmd);

    int lastIdInserted = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());

    return true;
}
```

EDIT

Conforme pedido em comentário, se é a `PROCEDURE` que retorna o valor, ficaria assim:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SaveProfessionalUser
@id int,
@title varchar(50)

AS
BEGIN       
    INSERT INTO ProfessionalType VALUES (@title)
    RETURN SCOPE_IDENTITY()
END
```

### Aplicação:

```
using (_context)
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SaveProfessionalUser", _context.Connection);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idProfessionalUser", pUser.IdProfessionalUser);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@title", pUser.Title);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    int ultimoIdInserido = (Int32)cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

    return true;
}
```

Comment: como pegar o resultado la na minha função dentro do codebehind?

Comment: @LuizNegrini Atualizei.

Comment: esta dando erro no "context.Connection"

Comment: Erro meu. É `_context`.

Comment: Ok, mas não existe uma forma de retornar na mesma procedure do "SaveProfessionalUser", tipo um "rerturn" mesmo dentro da procedure, por que desta forma estamos realizando um outro select, e era isso que eu não queria fazer... é boa prática? Se for tudo bem.

Comment: Existe sim. Só colocar na última linha da `PROCEDURE` um `return @@IDENTITY` e trocar `this._context.ExecuteProcedure(cmd);` por `int ultimoIdInserido = (Int32)cmd.ExecuteScalar();`. Note que é preciso definir a `connection` de `cmd` assim como eu fiz com `cmd2`, que agora pode ser removido.

Comment: Atualiza a resposta, blz?

Comment: @LuizNegrini Veja agora.

Comment: Dê uma olhada [nesta edição](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9305). Foi rejeitada por entendermos que fica a seu critério alterar a resposta assim ou não.

Comment: Só queria acrescentar que foi rejeitado tal edição, mas, tem um pouco de razão porque a resposta contém erros de código ... @CiganoMorrisonMendez se puder arrumar.

Comment: Deviam ter aprovado. Ele só alterou pro que está funcionando.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez Por que `SELECT IDENT_CURRENT` seria melhor que o output? Essa forma de fazer não poderia dar problema, caso outro registro fosse inserido na tabela entre o comando de `INSERT` e o `SELECT IDENT_CURRENT` ?

Answer (score 1):

Uma forma utilizada pelo [Entity Framework](http://www.asp.net/entity-framework) e executando com [@@ROWCOUNT](http://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms187316.aspx) E [scope_identity()](http://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms190315.aspx).

```
ALTER PROCEDURE SaveProfessionalUser
@id int,
@title varchar(50)

AS
BEGIN       
    INSERT INTO ProfessionalType VALUES (@title);
    SELECT id FROM ProfessionalType WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 AND id = scope_identity();
END
```

Em relação `scope_identity`, `identity` e `ident_current`, o site diz: Retorna o último valor de identidade inserido em uma coluna de identidade no mesmo escopo. Um escopo é um módulo: um procedimento armazenado, gatilho, função ou lote. Portanto, duas instruções estarão no mesmo escopo se eles estiverem no mesmo procedimento armazenado, função ou lote (***Fonte e Crédito***: http://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms190315.aspx (tradução)), ou seja, se você fizer qualquer uma das três e elas estiverem dentro do mesmo procedimento (Procedure) vão funcionar do mesmo jeito, resgatando o último elemento inserido.

SCOPE_IDENTITY, IDENT_CURRENT, e @@IDENTITY são funções semelhantes porque retornam valores que são inseridos em colunas de identidade. (***Fonte e Crédito***: http://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms190315.aspx (tradução))

Com esse exemplo de `Procedure` que eu postei ficaria seu código mais ou menos assim, sendo que está utilizando SQLClient (SqlConnection e SqlCommand)?

```
int idInserido = 0;
using (_context)
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SaveProfessionalUser");
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idProfessionalUser", pUser.IdProfessionalUser);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@title", pUser.Title);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    idInserido = int.Parse(this._context.ExecuteScalar().ToString());

    return true;
}
```

*Referências:*

- [SCOPE_IDENTITY (Transact-SQL)](http://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms190315.aspx)
- [@@ROWCOUNT (Transact-SQL)](http://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms187316.aspx)

Comment: como pegar o resultado la na minha função dentro do codebehind?

Comment: por isso Luiz Negrini eu te perguntei como ta utilizando, seria um SQLConnection ou Entity Framework???

Comment: @LuizNegrini conseguiu?

Comment: SqlConnection  ok?