# Dúvida com tempo de gravação de dados em tabelas mestre-detalhe?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

Após fazer a inserção de um registro, eu utilizo o `select max(IDControle)` para recuperar o id da tabela para gravar os itens.

Quando o tempo é de apenas 1 segundo, observei que os itens foram gravados todos no 1º registro. Alguém tem alguma ideia de como isso poderia ser evitado?

```
insert into TB_C_ORCAMENTO (descricaosituacao) values ('exemplo');
select max(controle) from TB_C_ORCAMENTO;
insert into TB_D_ORCAMENTO (controle, descricaoproduto) values (10, 'teste');
```

Comment: Não entendi muito bem a sua pergunta, poderia por favor explicar um pouco melhor?

Comment: Coloca o que você fez, dê exemplo do que acontece.

Comment: Quando se tem 2 tabelas é a gravação é feito com diferença de 1 segundo observei que os itens são gravados com o ID da primeira consulta. Me diga o que não entendeu?

Answer (score 0):

Esta maneira não é muito boa de pegar o último Id inserido. Por condições de concorrência, este Id pode ter sido alterado entre um comando e outro.

[Nesta resposta coloco três alternativas que podem ser usadas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/15714/stored-procedure-com-par%C3%A2metro-de-sa%C3%ADda-sendo-o-id-da-%C3%BAltima-inser%C3%A7%C3%A3o-c/15716#15716). O contexto é dentro de *Stored Procedure*, mas podem ser usadas no código da sua aplicação se a `DbConnection` não for fechada.